# Points of the sheaf topos over Blass' category

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, nonstandard-analysis

There is a site $\textsf{Blass}$ used for (constructive) non-standard analysis, whose objects are sets equipped with a filter, and morphisms are continuous functions defined up to a small set. (It is the localization of the category of filter-sets on the inclusion maps of large subsets.) We can equip it with the coherent / pre-canonical topology, and generate a Grothendieck topos $\textsf{Sh}(\textsf{Blass})$. Moerdijk asked in [*A model for intuitionistic non-standard arithmetic*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82327702.pdf) what the points of this topos are. Is there any progress made on describing these points explicitly?